# Godaddy not sending emails throws SMTPAuthenticationError on Django

Tags: django

I have the following settings on my settings file in django

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@website.com'
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and when I try and send an email it throws this error

```
    SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact-ajax
    (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [BYAPR02CA0052.namprd02.prod.outlook.com 2023-10-25T10:46:26.078Z 08DBD4986B1B4B4D]')

    ...


    Traceback:

    File "/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
      54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/sammy/webapp/prestige/prestige/views.py" in contact_ajax
      130.      msg.send()
```

I know the logins are fine because I've just logged in with them to godaddy webmail

I know there's no need for app password for this